# Publish on bintray using the gradle-bintray-plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, bintray

I have an Android-Library that I would like to publish on bintray.

So far so good, I am using the gradle-bintray-plugin 1.2 with the following configuration:

```
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "android" // thats how my maven repository is called on bintray
        name = "mylibrary"
        websiteUrl = "https://somewebsite" // replaced this, since the project should not matter
        issueTrackerUrl = 'some issuetracker url'
        vcsUrl = "some repository"
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = true
        version {
            // the 2 functions here, are building the version number
            name = versionNameBuild() // i.e. 1.0.0-SomeName
            vcsTag = versionName()  // 1.0.0
            gpg {
                // keys are uploaded
                sign = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first issue I ran into, was that after I uploaded the library the Version number was "unspecified". Meaning, that the file was uploaded successfully, but it was called smth. like "mylibrary-unspecified.aar". I figured out that I had to additionally specify the project version number in gradle.

like this:

```
project.version = "1.0.1"
```

After that, this was working fine. Now I have only 2 Questions left:

I would expect my files to be uploaded like this:

```
$BINTRAYUSERNAME/$REPONAME/$PACKAGENAME/$VERSION/*.aar
```

But they are actually uploaded to smth like this:

```
$BINTRAYUSERNAME/$REPONAME/$PROJECT_FOLDERNAME_OF_ANDROID_STUDIO/$SUBDIRECTORY_OF_THE_LIBRARY/$VERSION/*.aar
```

Can I change this "path" somehow? Does it matter?

Which leads me to my next question. 
How can I specify the maven group-type? I mean it's a maven repository right? So I should be able to set this up? Is this may be related to my first question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I change this "path" somehow? Does it matter?

Yes and yes. This path changed, as soon as I used the group variable:

```
group = "my.awesome.group"
```

This solves the second Question as well. The path of the uploaded file is then:

```
$BINTRAYUSERNAME/$REPONAME/$PACKAGENAME/$GROUPPATH/$VERSION/*.aar
```

I recommend using for Android libraries the [example script](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-examples/blob/master/gradle-aar-example/build.gradle).