# How to upload module to JCenter using gradle bintray plugin?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, bintray, jcenter

I am sorry if I am being too stupid but I just can't make it work... I have an Android Module Project in AS that I want to upload to JCenter - using gradle bintray plugin from [JFrog](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin). I follow [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en?fb_comment_id=867773669945818_908997052490146&comment_id=908997052490146#f3f8a555d) tutorial in order to create the repository on bintray and I ended up with the following build.gradle for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty('bintray.user')
    key = properties.getProperty('bintray.apikey')

    configurations = ['published', 'archives']

    dryRun = false
    publish = true

    pkg {
        repo = 'maven'
        name = 'custom-searchable'

        desc = 'This repository contains a library that aims to provide a custom searchable interface for android applications'

        websiteUrl = 'https://github.com/...'
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://github.com/.../issues'
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/....git'

        licenses = ['The Apache Software License, Version 2.0']
        labels = ['android', 'searchable', 'interface', 'layout']
        publicDownloadNumbers = true

        version {
            name = '1.0'
            desc = 'Bintray integration test'
            vcsTag = '1.0'
        }
    }
}

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'custom-searchable'

    publishedGroupId = 'br.com.edsilfer'
    libraryName = 'CustomSearchable'
    artifact = 'custom-searchable'

    libraryDescription = 'This repository contains a library that aims to provide a custom searchable interface for android applications'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/...'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/....git'

    libraryVersion = '1.0'

    developerId = '...'
    developerName = '...'
    developerEmail = '...'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

And this one for the project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

After running the task `gradle bintrayUpload` (it finishes sucessfully) my repository in bintray looks like that:

[image: first hierarchy]
And when you open the unspecified folder you'll find this:

[image]

So questions!

1. Why version is being upload like unspecifiend?
2. I can't compile my project with the given group id:artifact:version, when trying to build it on AS it says that it fails to resolve the path to the artifact.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you forget adding version attribute in your build.gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the standard configuration provided by the gradle plugin, which do not specify library version.

I'm using the publication instead:

```
...
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

...

bintray {
    ...
    publications = ['Publication']
    pkg {
        ...
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        Publication(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
            groupId 'com.lib'
            artifactId 'help-er'
            version '0.1'
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use configurations check this question: [Publish on bintray using the gradle-bintray-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381719/publish-on-bintray-using-the-gradle-bintray-plugin)